# Microchip problem with usb_device.c file, getting errors i cannot solve

Tags: c, pic, microchip

Well the problem is these errors

I have not touched these files but just downloaded the legacy mla and used the files. So I'm assuming there is a problem with my directories in some way.
I have the path to the microchip/include file and some of the code works. So now when im building the project i encounter these problems. I've tried changing the paths, using linker folders but nothing seems to work.

I know the the functions are in the usb_device_local.h file and its included but still nothing

im using mplabx v5.15, and xc32 compiler v2.15. Also a older pic32mx

```
build/default/production/_ext/2021492214/usb_device.o: In function `_USB1Interrupt':
c:/microchip_solutions_v2013-06-15/microchip/usb/usb_device.c:887: undefined reference to `USER_USB_CALLBACK_EVENT_HANDLER'
c:/microchip_solutions_v2013-06-15/microchip/usb/usb_device.c:937: undefined reference to `USER_USB_CALLBACK_EVENT_HANDLER'
c:/microchip_solutions_v2013-06-15/microchip/usb/usb_device.c:995: undefined reference to `USER_USB_CALLBACK_EVENT_HANDLER'
build/default/production/_ext/2021492214/usb_device.o: In function `USBStdSetCfgHandler':
c:/microchip_solutions_v2013-06-15/microchip/usb/usb_device.c:2180: undefined reference to `USER_USB_CALLBACK_EVENT_HANDLER'
build/default/production/_ext/2021492214/usb_device.o: In function `USBStdGetDscHandler':
c:/microchip_solutions_v2013-06-15/microchip/usb/usb_device.c:2218: undefined reference to `device_dsc'
c:/microchip_solutions_v2013-06-15/microchip/usb/usb_device.c:2218: undefined reference to `device_dsc'
c:/microchip_solutions_v2013-06-15/microchip/usb/usb_device.c:2226: undefined reference to `USB_CD_Ptr'
c:/microchip_solutions_v2013-06-15/microchip/usb/usb_device.c:2226: undefined reference to `USB_CD_Ptr'
c:/microchip_solutions_v2013-06-15/microchip/usb/usb_device.c:2242: undefined reference to `USB_SD_Ptr'
c:/microchip_solutions_v2013-06-15/microchip/usb/usb_device.c:2242: undefined reference to `USB_SD_Ptr'
build/default/production/_ext/2021492214/usb_device.o: In function `USBSuspend':
c:/microchip_solutions_v2013-06-15/microchip/usb/usb_device.c:2437: undefined reference to `USER_USB_CALLBACK_EVENT_HANDLER'
build/default/production/_ext/2021492214/usb_device.o: In function `USBWakeFromSuspend':
c:/microchip_solutions_v2013-06-15/microchip/usb/usb_device.c:2463: undefined reference to `USER_USB_CALLBACK_EVENT_HANDLER'
build/default/production/_ext/2021492214/usb_device.o: In function `USBCtrlTrfSetupHandler':
c:/microchip_solutions_v2013-06-15/microchip/usb/usb_device.c:2657: undefined reference to `USER_USB_CALLBACK_EVENT_HANDLER'
build/default/production/_ext/2021492214/usb_device.o: In function `USBCheckStdRequest':
c:/microchip_solutions_v2013-06-15/microchip/usb/usb_device.c:2879: undefined reference to `USER_USB_CALLBACK_EVENT_HANDLER'
build/default/production/_ext/2021492214/usb_device.o: In function `USBStdFeatureReqHandler':
c:/microchip_solutions_v2013-06-15/microchip/usb/usb_device.c:3041: undefined reference to `USER_USB_CALLBACK_EVENT_HANDLER'
build/default/production/_ext/2021492214/usb_device.o:c:/microchip_solutions_v2013-06-15/microchip/usb/usb_device.c:3071: more undefined references to `USER_USB_CALLBACK_EVENT_HANDLER' follow
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 255 exit status
```

Comment: Have you properly linked everything?

Comment: I've been following http://wordpress.codewrite.co.uk/pic/2013/07/26/usb-interface-using-pic16f1455-2/ this guide, and also looking at a couple of examples and ive included the same paths and done what it says in the readme files

Comment: Is there a `Microchip/lib` folder or something like that? I'm unable to view the actual code myself, from where I'm at now

Comment: No, first its Microchip/USB, TCPIP Stack, Common. Well different technologies for different uses. Then there is a Microchip/include/USB ... with about the same structure

Comment: just for completeness, can you also mention what version of MPLAB or MPLAB x you are using and which compiler and version?

Comment: mplabx v5.15, and xc32 compiler v2.15

Comment: thanks-- I also forgot to ask, which PIC? I didn't see that in the question. Maybe update the question with all that info too would be good.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the compiler you are using and the date that this tutorial was made leads me to believe that the some of the tutorial is not only out of date but the the main/interrupt code will be incompatible with the type of PIC and compiler you are using. (So even if you could get rid of these errors you'd just get more unless you know what you are doing!)

However, if you have followed the tutorial correctly and added the `HardwareProfile.h`, `usb_device.c`, `usb_descriptors.c` and `main.c` files from the tutorial (except the `interrupt` and `#config` stuff in `main.c` as they will be incompatible with the PIC32), it should build successfully albeit with a bunch of unrelated `PLIB` warnings.

The file structure should be like this below:

[image: File structure]

`usb_descriptors.c`, `main.c`, `HardwareProfile.h`, `usb_config.h` should all be your own created .c files via `New --> C Source File` to your project and adding the code from the tutorial. These should then exist in your project folder.

Whereas `usb_device.c` and `usb_function_cdc.c` should be from the microchip mla folder

As the tutorial states, albeit not very clearly, you must set the include directories correctly.

To do this go to Project Options then:

`xc32 (Global Options) --> Common include dirs`

set the following:

[image: Include Directories]

(Whereever MLA is installed , mine is probably a different version)

And do the same for

`xc32-as General --> Preprocessor Include directories` and

`xc32-as General --> Assembler Include directories`

Microchip recommends on their [website](https://www.microchip.com/mplab/microchip-libraries-for-applications) `32-bit PIC32 customers (except for PIC32MM) should use MPLAB Harmony Integrated Software Framework which includes TCPIP, USB, Graphics, File systems and more`. If you are using PICMM then I'd recommend the latest version of MLA, not 2013 version, you can find on the [Microchip MLA](https://www.microchip.com/mplab/microchip-libraries-for-applications) page. If not I'd recommend learning their [harmony plugin](https://www.microchip.com/mplab/mplab-harmony).

Comment: im using a pic32mx processor a older one and rewriting code from a previous project adding the usb compability. Should  i try a older compiler or just try to fix the problems as they come up?. Ive done most of what you have written but waited with some parts. I will go over this and do exactly the same. Thanks alot for the fast response. I can add that i have tried the example projects in the mla and those built just fine with a few warnings tho

Comment: It does seem to compile with my version xc32 v2.05 which isn't far off from yours. The MLA stuff will compile but the stuff from the tutorial probably won't (specifically some things in `main.c`) saying that it's probably better to use a later version of MLA (there's a 2018 version) or move onto Harmony which has much greater support.

Comment: Yah im just using the tutorial as a base taking chunks of code and editing based on the usb documentation for my processor. I tried a later version of mla but that only had support for pic32mm. Yah harmony looks nice from what ive seen, i will give this a few more days and see how it looks.